# Whats the worst thing a command injection vulnerability do?

Tags: web-application

Suppose my team made a web application which has command injection vulnerability, what's the worst (most harmful) thing an attack can do to us?

Comment: What's the worst thing you can do with your command line access? Delete everything from the server? Run up massive AWS bills by spinning up expensive instances using scripts? Send out junk mail to everyone who signed up to your application, risking fines? Depends what you consider the most harmful!

Comment: Compromise your website so that it infects visitors with malware, ruining their day and your reputation. Use the server as a starting point to attack other systems, which means FBI will come to you first as the origin of the attacks... The question is too broad and any answers will be primarily opinion based. I propose to close it.

Comment: Inject arbitrary code into the server, making it perform DoS attacks, distribute child pornography, engage in international espionage, kill a kitten, and replace all the semicolons in your C files with homographs. I mean really the sky is the limit once the server is executing malicious code.

Answer (score 1):

So, a command injection is as bad as the [code injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Code_Injection).

> In Command Injection, the attacker extends the default functionality of the application, which execute system commands, without the necessity of injecting code.

In the command injection, the attacker can inject his own operating system commands. This means he literally take over your entire server and destroy all things you have made. So yea, it's pretty harmful if you have a vulnerability where an attacker can execute code on the server itself.

Here's a cheatsheet how you can prevent command injections: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet